# What are billed when you calling Ms Graph from Azure function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, azure-billing

Actualy I have a web app (SPA) that send files directly to the graph (Onedrive), this is great because I'm not charge for the incoming bandwidth so what ever the file size is, i'm not billed for that.

Now, I would like to send my file to an Azure Function, the incoming bandwidth will be free again, I'll be charge for the function storage and usage (this is normal), but what will be charge if i send my file to the graph inside of the Function ?

Web => Graph = Free

Web => Function => Graph = (Function price) +  ???

I know that bandwidth inside azure same region is free, but I don't know if my function (France, center) is in the same region of the Graph endpoint i use ...

Could someone help me find this information please ?

Comment: Regardless of whether the Graph endpoint you're hitting is in France or not, you will be charged for data egress from Azure Function as they are separate systems.

Comment: I agree with @Gaurav above. For more info, you may want to check with Microsoft support to know more about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarize from the comments:

As Gaurav and Dev mentioned, regardless of whether the Graph endpoint you're hitting is in France or not, you will be charged for data egress from Azure Function as they are separate systems.

For more accurate spending, you can [create a support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) on azure portal for pricing or cost. It's free if your question is not related to technology.